# Que debería ir exactamente en el Modulo Core y en el Modulo Shared en Angular

Tags: angular, modulos, core

He visto que en muchas estructuras de proyectos usan un modulo Core y un modulo Shared, Así que he leído y buscado información (incluso en la documentación de Angular) pero aún no me queda del todo claro.

Hasta ahora, esto es lo que he entendido:

`En el modulo CORE irían servicios que solo quisiera importar una sola vez en mi aplicación y este módulo solo será importada una única vez y esta importación solo será en el App.module. Y en el modulo SHARED irían componentes, pipes o cualquier otra cosa que podría importar mas de una vez en otros módulos`

Así, que según lo que he podido entender, en el módulo CORE se importarían modulos como el HttpClient? además irían cosas como los guards en este mismo módulo?

Colocando un caso de ejemplo:

Supongamos que tengo un modulo `Autenticacion`, el cuál tiene componentes como: Ingreso, Registro, Recuperacion de contraseña, etc, en este modulo tendría un servicio de autenticación en el cuál pueda hacer todas las peticiones a la API para el ingreso, registro y recuperación de contraseña. Esto estaría correcto? en el modulo CORE solo debería estar importado el HttpClient y nada más que eso?

Estoy un poco enrredado, y sinceramente por mas que leo aún no me queda claro las diferencias entre ambos modulos, aunque se que eso puede variar según los requisitos del proyecto, pero también se que debe haber algo con lo que partir de forma correcta y evitar problemas a futuro. Ojalá y alguien con experiencia en este tema me pudiera ayudar, estaría enormemente agradecido.

Comment: Actualmente no se utiliza esa estructura. Angular trabaja con inyección de depencias y por defecto utiliza la misma instancia de un servicio para todas las llamadas que hagas (Singleton).  Por otro lado el `sharedComponent` se utiliza para tener todas las herramientas de uso común en un solo lugar. El problema de esta aproximación es que puedes caer en el vicio de querer cargar todo y crear una especie de "ironia" con el lazy loading cuyo objetivo es prevenir la carga de componentes innecesarios. Mi recomendación es solo utilizar `sharedComponent` y lo menos posible.

Comment: @Legna te refieres a que el modulo Core ya no es necesario? ya yo lo había creado por que veo que absolutamente todos recomiendan crear un modulo Core y un Módulo Shared. en cuándo a lo otro que comentas, no se si te entendí bien. Te refieres a que si dentro del componente Shared hay 10 componentes importados, y supongamos que en 1 modulo necesito importar 1 solo componente de los que está en el modulo shared, al hacer la importacion del moulo shared estaría importando los 10 componentes?

Comment: No es necesario Core en cuanto a gestión interna. Si lo usas para organizarte, pues adelante, pero puedes hacer las importaciones directamente y la inyección de depencias seguirá funcionando. Con respecto al ShareComponent, es correcto. El nombre es un estandar que se utiliza en angular y basicamente lo que haces es poner ahi todo lo que siempre necesitas tener disponible. Es un modulo a final de cuentas, y los modulos cargan todos los componentes, pipes, servicios y más modulos que les importes de una sola vez cuando son llamados.

Comment: Ok. En caso de seguir usando el modulo core, como se haría con lo siguiente: tengo un modulo auth, dentro tengo una carpeta components y services. dentro de services tengo un servicio donde por supuesto importo el HttpClient. en el modulo Core, importe HttpClientModule y el arreglo de imports lo coloqué también, pero me daba error nullInjector, solo por probar, hice lo mismo pero en el app.module y ahí si funciona. Me haría falto alguna importación u otra cosa en el Core module para que funcione desde ahí ?

Comment: No sabría decirte sin ver el código.